# How to create a masked array using numpy.ma imported by PyCall in Julia

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, julia

I want to create a masked array using `numpy.ma` imported by PyCall in Julia.

A Python example in the the help of `is_masked()` in `numpy.ma` module.

```
>>> import numpy.ma as ma
>>> x = ma.masked_equal([0, 1, 0, 2, 3], 0)
>>> x
masked_array(data = [-- 1 -- 2 3],
      mask = [ True False  True False False],
      fill_value=999999)
>>> ma.is_masked(x)
True
```

I tried to translate it into Julia using PyCall.

```
julia> using PyCall
julia> @pyimport numpy.ma as ma
julia> x = ma.masked_equal([0, 1, 0, 2, 3], 0);
julia> x
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
 1
 0
 2
 3
julia> ma.is_masked(x)
false
```

The above code is NOT working. It fails to create a Python object. It just creates a usual Julia array. I tried other ways such as `ma.array([1, 2, 3], mask=[0, 0, 1])`, but still not working.

However, from a example in https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl,

```
julia> @pyimport Bio.Seq as s
julia> @pyimport Bio.Alphabet as a
julia> my_dna = s.Seq("AGTACACTGGT", a.generic_dna)
PyObject Seq('AGTACACTGGT', DNAAlphabet())
julia> my_dna[:find]("ACT")
5
```

In this case, the python object can be created directly without effort.

Question: What's wrong with my translation? How can I create a numpy masked array in Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your translation — this looks like a bug in PyCall.  PyCall tries to map Julia and Python types back and forth so that you can seamlessly use Julia's arrays like NumPy arrays (for example).  In this case, it looks like it's a bit overzealous in doing the conversion.

You can disable the conversion by using `pycall` directly. The second argument is the return type:

```
julia> x = pycall(ma.masked_equal, Any, [0,1,0,2,3], 0)
PyObject masked_array(data = [-- 1L -- 2L 3L],
             mask = [ True False  True False False],
       fill_value = 0)

julia> ma.is_masked(x)
true
```

This is a bug in the python type identification.  PyCall thinks that the `masked_array` object type should map to a builtin array, so that's why it defaults to returning an array back:

```
julia> pytype_query(x)
Array{Int64,N}
```

Comment: Could you [open an issue over at PyCall.jl](https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl/issues/new)?  That way you'll be able to track its progress yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will open an issue about masked array in numpy.ma!